# Unable to find login method for Bouyweather site

Tags: python, authentication, web-scraping, python-requests

Some information is only accessible after login. I'm able to scrape weather forecast for 2 days as a free version. I have a paid account which shows weather forecast up to 16 days. While using a normal web browser I can see the information. In Python, I'm not able to log in, so that information is not accessible.

This is the website:

http://www.buoyweather.com/forecast/marine-weather/@28.217289755957054,-95.701904296875

Running Python 3 with `requests`, I was able to config proxy and parse code on free version of web site.

I have searched on buoyweather for any reference to my account id. It appears that an ID is generated by the website. It is always the same. Also, I have found a `crossDomainID`, which is always the same as well.

I'm trying to use `session()` and `.post` to insert the info, but it is not logging in. I have tried to insert the information in the login page and in the weather page. Both with results.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page_login = "https://www.buoyweather.com/sign-in?destination=/"

payload = {'email':"XXX.XX@XXX.XXX",
           'password':"XXXX"}

payload2 = {'crossDomainId': "a5114849-4604-4b38-ae0b-79fc6664231a",
'plan': "premium",
'userId': "XXXXX",
"activeEmbed": "nilEmbed",
"is_chatting": "false",
"widgetShown": "false",
"id":"XXXX",
"anonymousId":"202be0c7-590b-44d7-b001-a3e1591d216a",
"email":"XXXXXXX",
"entitlements":"bw_premium",
"identify":"false",
"type":"logged_in"}

proxies = {'http': 'http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'}
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.90 Safari/537.36'}

s = requests.session()
s.proxies.update(proxies)

page_link = "http://www.buoyweather.com/forecast/marine-weather/@28.217289755957054,-95.701904296875"
```

I have tried all combinations in inserting the information at either login or link, `payload` or `payload2`. No Success

```
r = s.post(page_login, data = payload2,proxies=proxies,headers=headers)
r = s.post(page_login, data = payload,proxies=proxies,headers=headers)
```

After printing `r.text` I was expecting to have the same information has a paid user. Instead I have free user.

Comment: maybe you could [ask them directly](https://support.buoyweather.com/hc/en-us/requests/new)?  in lieu of that, chrome dev-tools suggests their login page actually sends the username/password `services.surfline.com`, I'd suggest using developer tools in your favourite browser to figure out what's actually going on.  note that this [might be illegal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping#Legal_issues)

Comment: note, it's generally OK to do this for "personal" use, it mostly gets awkward if you're doing this commercially or if you hit their servers fast enough that their service suffers.  [Chrome's dev-tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/) are amazing if you're exploring this sort of thing, but it might be worth starting with something simpler first.  maybe set up a [Flask web server](https://palletsprojects.com/p/flask/) on your computer to see how things work

Comment: Hi Sam. Thank you very much for your help. I have requested both their permission and help. Thank you for your advice. I will wait for their reply before anything else, but how did you find out that login goes by that link?

Comment: For anyone with the same problem, I have changed the library to Selenium. It is slower but solved the Login problem. I have other upsets but will try to solve them before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for helping me Sam. Much appreciated.

Could not solve using requests library, but worked easily with Selenium.

```
#imports chrome webdriver in path
chromedriver = 'C:\\chromedriver.exe'
browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Python/chromedriver")
#wait to load pages
browser.implicitly_wait(200)
#go to link
browser.get('https://www.buoyweather.com/sign-in?destination=/map/nearby-region')
print ('Gonna Login')
#searches for email and password fields
username = browser.find_element_by_id('email')
password = browser.find_element_by_id('password')
#types email and password
username.send_keys('xxxxxxxxxxx')
password.send_keys('xxxxxxxxxx')
print('sign in')
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Sign In"]').click()
print ('Logged In')
browser.get('http://www.buoyweather.com/forecast/marine-weather/favorites/FPSO+CMB/@-25.18505888358066,-42.890625')
```

Hope it helps anyone.